# Reader no lee en el primer if c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

```
namespace Regext.operaciones
{
    class grillas
    {



        MySqlDataReader dr = null;

        public void llenargrillaclienteempresa(DataGridView grilla_empresa, Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMaterialTextbox txt_buscar_empresa)
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from tb_empresa where rut_empresa = '" + txt_buscar_empresa.Text + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if(dr.Read() == true){

                 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        grilla_empresa.DataSource = dt;

                }else{
                    MessageBox.Show("no se encontro rut");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }



        }


    }
}
```

tengo esta clase que sirve para llenar las grillas pero el reader no lee osea no entra al primer if pero si deferencia si el rut esta o no en la base de datos.

Comment: Leyendo los comentarios parece que te está lanzando alguna excepción. Necesitamos conocer cual es para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Si esta lanzando algun error edita tu pregunta y muestranosla.

Comment: Hola sebastian, te recomiendo que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para escribir mejores preguntas. Por ejemplo, ¿recibes algún error? ¿Si haces debug. cuál es el recorrido que se hace? Intenta definir mejor el problema

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente te voy a dejar un trozo de código que puedes ensayar para corregir el problema que estas planteando. Pero ten en cuenta que tú código presenta varias malas practicas, a la hora de trabajar con conexiones a bases de datos, esto te lo escribo para que lo investigues mas adelante.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from tb_empresa where rut_empresa = '" + txt_buscar_empresa.Text + "'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);    
    da.Fill(dt);            
}
catch (Exception f)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}


if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("no se encontro rut");
else
   grilla_empresa.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: si se que el * es una mala practica ademas el select.

Comment: pero aun asi sigue entrando al if =( entra directo en el catch

Comment: @sebastianbizamainostroza, ¿Cuál es el error que muestra en el _catch_ ?

Comment: Como indica @Davilo, escribe el error que pasa por el catch para poder colaborarte de una mejor manera.